# Парсинг текстового файла и перемещение файлов по пути

Tags: парсер, powershell

Доброго времени суток, 
  встретился с проблемой считывания пути до файла из текстового файла и перемещения его. 
К примеру есть файл List.txt в котором содержатся полные пути по которым лежат файлы:
C:\Users\Администратор\DocumentsPowerShell\NonActualFiles\SourcePath\001-DI-U2.199600.pdf12
C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\PowerShell\NonActualFiles\SourcePath\Статистика по проблемам и заявкам.xlsx
и.т.д.

Требуется переместить файлы по этим путям в другую папку т.е. распарсить файл и переместить эти файлы в другую папку.

Из предположения только это, но оно не работает.

```
$SourcePath = "C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\PowerShell\List.txt"

 Select-String -Path $SourcePath -Pattern SourcePath -AllMatches -Encoding utf8 -SimpleMatch

$Destination = "C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\PowerShell\DestinationPath"

foreach ($SourcePath in $SourcePaths) {
Move-Item -Path $SourcePath -Destination $Destination
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет только о перемещении файлов и в данном файле только строки с путями, то:

```
$SourcePath = Get-Content "C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\PowerShell\List.txt"
$Destination = "C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\PowerShell\DestinationPath"
Move-Item $SourcePath -Destination $Destination
```

Get-Content считывает все данные из файла. Каждая строка файла воспринимается как отдельный объект.

Comment: Так ведь оно не будет работать если там больше одного пути, для этого насколько я понимаю нужно заносить их в массив, в этом то и загвоздка.

Comment: Почему не будет? Get-Content каждую строчку воспринимает, как отдельный объект и отрабатывает ее. Соответственно, если у вас в List.txt в каждой строчке отдельный и конечный путь к файлу, то он ее перемещает в переменную $SourcePath и делает Move-Item в $Destination . Данный пример отрабатывает, проверено.